# Цвет и размер у Гало Unity5

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо поменять размер или цвет [гало](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-Halo.html). К сожалению, в руководстве не написано, как это делать из кода.

```
Behaviour myHalo = (Behaviour)GetComponent("Halo");
```

Позволяет только включать и выключать его:

```
myHalo.enabled = true;
myHalo.enabled = false;
```

При попытке задать цвет:

```
myHalo.color = Color.magenta;
```

выводит:

> 'Behaviour' does not contain a definition for 'color' and no extension method 'color' accepting a first argument of type 'Behaviour' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: дай-ка повангую : Halo является подклассом Behaviour, а значит - нужно `Halo myHalo = (Halo)GetComponent("Halo")`, не?

Comment: @AlexanderPozharskii Что, простите? В таком виде оно даже не определяется. Как указано в посте, обращение к гало успешно работает. Только обращение это включить или выключить. Вопрос то в том, можно ли как то поменять цвет на нем,из скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не дождавшись ответа, и посмотрев англоязычные источники, с сожалением признаю, что способов изменить цвет  гало из скрипта пока нет. Но, есть обходной путь - добавляем вместо гало источник света, щёлкаем там Draw Halo, и из скрипта обращаемся с нему следующий образом

```
this.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = true;
this.GetComponent<Light>().color = Color.magenta;
```

Цвет успешно меняется. Аналогичным образом можно поменять и другие свойства света.